What extension to use for the ADO task 'Azure-Kusto.PublishToADX.PublishToADX.PublishToADX@3'
I have this ADO task in my Azure devops pipeline which is not running looking for the extension.
'Azure-Kusto.PublishToADX.PublishToADX.PublishToADX@3'
What exact extension do I need to download from marketplace to run this task in ADO pipeline.

This task is form the extension Azure Data Explorer - Pipeline Tools.

This task is from the extension Azure Data Explorer - Pipeline Tools. the current latest version of this task is v4 (4.*).
After installing the extension into your Azure DevOps organization/collection:

In classic pipelines, you can find and add this task via searching for the name "Azure Data Explorer Command".


In YAML pipeline, you can add this task via referencing the name "PublishToADX@4".
steps:
. . .

- task: PublishToADX@4
   displayName: 'Kusto Command'
   inputs:
     . . .




